# Interpret string with spaces encased in quotes as one "item"?

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I'm making an ajax console for a site that I'm an admin on for other administrators to use.

Anyway, I have a bunch of commands they can use like "getid someusername", but the usernames can also have spaces in them like "getid some other name".  I know that command line PHP scripts take arguments with spaces when they are encased in quotes.  Is this functionality included in PHP or will I need to write it myself?

Comment: what are you asking? is it hard to type " or ' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this functionality included in PHP or will I need to write it myself?

You can always easily test it for yourself  (see [`$argv`](http://php.net/manual/reserved.variables.argv.php)), however as far as I know, that functionality is included in PHP (or more correctly, with the shell).

Answer (score 0):

If the argument contains spaces, simply put it between brackets, and in your code, use [trim()](http://php.net/trim): `$username = trim($argument, '"');`.